# Django redirect views with parameter/context

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I have register view in my django app, that redirects to the homepage:

```
def register(request):
   ...register...
   return redirect("/")


def homepage(request):
    users = User.objects.all().order_by('username')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'users': users})
```

I want to add variable `new_user` that would tell the homepage if user is new. I would pass variable from register view to the homepage view and than into the template where i would handle it:

```
{% if new_user %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{% endif %}
```

But i dont know how to pass this variable from register view to homepage and than into the template.
Help is well appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve that would be to set a parameter in query:

```
def register(request):
   ...register...
   return redirect('/?new')


def homepage(request):
    is_new_user = 'new' in request.GET
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help you.

```
def register(request):
   ...register...
   users = User.objects.all().order_by('username')
   return redirect("/", {'users'=users })


def homepage(request,users):
```